# Diffusion of gases of different temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, gas

Let a box be divided into two parts by a partition. Let each part be filled in by the same gas in equal concentrations but different temperatures. Let the gases start diffusing through a hole in the partition.
Assume also that the temperature is each part is maintained constant.

> Is it true that the concentration of gas in the cooler part will be higher?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the question is about the time when the system reaches a *stationary state*, that is there is no more the net flow of gas between the partitions. Note that *stationary* does not mean *equilibrium* - there is still the constant flow of energy between the two partitions, but nothing changes with time.

We can now describe the gas in each partition by the ideal gas equation:
$$P_{1,2}=n_{1,2}k_BT_{1,2}.$$
The preassures at the hole are the same, $P_1 = P_2$ so we obtain:
$\frac{n_1}{n_2}=\frac{T_2}{T_1},$
that is the partition with the higher temperature has the lower concentration.

**Remark**
The weakness in my argument is assuming that the absence of net material flow means equal pressures - perhaps somebody could help me out here.